# Exibir um registro por quantidade e o valor que mais se repete de uma coluna

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema: preciso que seja exibido as localidades, o número de envios de cada uma (ou seja, quantas vezes o nome da localidade aparece na coluna) e a doença mais comum de cada localidade (ou seja, o nome da doença que mais se repete naquela localidade específica).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**POR EXEMPLO:**

- localidade: CroatÃ¡ 1
- número de envios: 4
- doença mais comum: Conjutivite

---

Tenho essas duas *query's* mas elas não funcionam juntas, apenas uma ou outra

```
SELECT localidade, count(localidade) AS qt FROM tb_grafico group by localidade;
```

---

```
SELECT localidade, tipo_doenca, COUNT(tipo_doenca) as qtidade FROM tb_grafico
where localidade='CroatÃ¡ 1'
GROUP BY tipo_doenca
ORDER BY COUNT(tipo_doenca) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

de preferência em uma única querry sql

Comment: o que já tentou fazer? Da uma lida no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do site, a ideia é ajudarmos a resolver dúvidas mais específicas ;)

Comment: sim eu tentei e consegui com duas querry's mas quando puxava os dados php a primeira querry não funcionava mais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha sugestão é que crie uma `VIEW` que totalize a quantidade baseado na localidade e na doença:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_grafico AS
  SELECT localidade,
         tipo_doenca,
         COUNT(localidade) AS quantidade
    FROM tb_grafico
   GROUP BY localidade,
            tipo_doenca;
```

Depois disso faça a seleção da maior doença na `vw_grafico`:

```
SELECT g.*,
       (SELECT SUM(g3.quantidade)
          FROM vw_grafico g3
         WHERE g3.localidade = g.localidade) AS total
  FROM vw_grafico g
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM vw_grafico g2
                   WHERE g2.localidade = g.localidade
                     AND g2.tipo_doenca <> g.tipo_doenca
                     AND g2.quantidade > g.quantidade)
```

Comment: mas ele está exibindo todas as doenças do bairro, eu só queria a localidade, doença que mais se repete e a quantidade para chamar no php e exibir apenas uma vez